# libvirt and qemu/kvm -snapshot option

Tags: kvm-virtualization, snapshot, libvirt, qemu

Using libvirt, I want to use QEMU's '-snapshot' option.  That way, when the machine shuts down, all of the disk changes that were made get destroyed.

Here is the manual for the -snapshot option:

> Write to temporary files instead of disk image files. In this case,
>              the raw disk image you use is not written back. You can however
>              force the write back by pressing C-a s.

Similar abilities exist that almost do what I want (qcow2 overlay images, libvirt backing store), but the difference is that I want a fresh environment every time I boot up the VM.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to add command-line switches that libvirt doesn't support yet is to create a wrapper script and change your VM's configuration to use it instead.  For example,

```
# cat >/usr/local/bin/qemu-snapshot <<'END'
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/qemu "$@" -snapshot
END
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/qemu-snapshot
# virsh -c qemu:///system edit my_vm
change
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu</emulator>
to
    <emulator>/usr/local/bin/qemu-snapshot</emulator>
```

(It might be `/usr/bin/kvm` or something like that for you.)

Comment: Nice solution, looking forward to playing around with this on other switches unsupported by libvirt too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  One further bit of trouble I had was I was getting the error "error: internal error cannot parse QEMU version number in ''".  I had to add my script to my apparmor profiles.  See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/490370

Answer (score 1):

You just have to send kvm's monitor `commit all` to make the equivalent of CTRL+a...

Answer (score 0):

Have you figured out how to commit snapshot changes to disk img?  C-a s doesn't seem to do squat.  even tried, ctrl ctrl ctrl-a s.  virsh doesn't have a commit command either.

If you figured it out, passing that along would be very helpful! :D

Answer (score 0):

note

```
xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0
```

in header, and just inspect that. This almost works!

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>...</name>
  <memory unit='KiB'>...</memory>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
  </os>

  <qemu:commandline>
     <qemu:arg value='-snapshot'/>
  </qemu:commandline>

  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>

    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/tmp/some/existing/image.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
<!--
    https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=832194
      <transient />
-->
    </disk>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Unfortunatelly, this hapen:

```
internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1: Device needs media, but drive is empty
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1: Device initialization failed.
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1: Device 'ide-hd' could not be initialized
```

But anyway this is much more clean way to pass custom qemu arguments