# How (if at all) is KVM used with enterprise workloads?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, scalability, software

This is sort of similar to [Q123566](https://serverfault.com/q/123566/175102), but I want to add a few clarifications:

- [KVM](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/virtualization/kvm-vs-vmware-comparison) is the Linux-kernel-based virtualization **technology** (specifically: a hypervisor) that underlies most non-Xen FOSS virtualization platforms/tools.
- [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/) is an atomic **tool**/utility/program, that, today, [fills](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/qemu-kvm/kvm.1.en.html) the role that `kvm(1)` *did* while its eponymous hypervisor was under development. It is capable of using `kvm(3)` as an emulation backend; this is its most efficient mode of operation on x86_64-based platforms.
- Neither of these are virtualization [solutions](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/virtualization/what-is-virtualization-management) in the way that ESXi and Hyper-V (which each pack their own, purpose-built, type-1 hypervisor) are.

  - A *solution* (not a tool or technology), whether developed in-house or acquired externally, is a *crucial* aspect of any enterprise IT deployment.

Clarifying that last point: a kernel module *per se* does not facilitate devops, nor does QEMU run itself. **A tool is not a solution** (though a sufficiently robust tool may lull a sysadmin into thinking their ad-hoc, in-house, undocumented solution is viable).

None but the most ["confident"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor) of sysadmins believe that an array of machines running manually-installed operating systems, configured by a (manually-administered) smattering of `systemd.unit(5)` files invoking various instances of `qemu-system-x86_64(1)`, is sustainable or scalable.

---

That gap—that KVM (partly due to being a type 2 hypervisor) is the only "odd one out"; it's a hypervisor *not* locked to a particular tool and/or solution—is where Red Hat's [virt-manager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-creating_guests_with_virt_manager), comes in. It *seems to be* (aside from [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org/), apparently a layer-on-top-of / interface-to virt-manger,) the only enterprise-grade QEMU-based (and, by extension, KVM-based) virtualization solution currently on the market.

But whereas many companies use ESXi<sup>[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+companies+use+esxi)</sup> and Hyper-V<sup>[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+companies+use+hyper-v)</sup>, it's hard to find any<sup>[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+companies+use+virt-manager)</sup> that use virt-manager. And while a handful of companies *identify as* using KVM-based solutions<sup>[4](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+companies+use+kvm)</sup>, information on *how* KVM is actually used is scarce.

So, how is KVM used with enterprise workloads, which can't afford the assorted risks of running on a shoestring shell-script-and-SSH infrastructure? Is it used at all? Do companies just commandeer something like [SaltStack](https://www.saltstack.com/) to corral KVM+QEMU as part of an in-house solution? Is virt-manager *actually* in wide use but a well-kept secret? I can't figure out why there's this information-black-hole around what is apparently the virtualization solution powering Red Hat, Inc's (and *nobody else*'s?) *entire* infrastructure.

Comment: Further compounding my confusion is the fact that this hypervisor is the only one privileged to be _built-in to_ the kernel which, itself, underlies _most_ virtualization as-implemented today, both host and guest sides...

Comment: I think this post is entirely off topic here as opinion based. Yes, some enterprises use Virt Manager. Also, Google Proxmox

Comment: @davidgo my question was very specific. Even if lots of companies (as I note **in my post**) _claim_ to use it, the operative word in the title was `how`.

Answer (score 1):

KVM is widely used in the cloud, both private and public:

- [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) uses KVM
- [AWS](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/11/07/aws_writes_new_kvm_based_hypervisor_to_make_its_cloud_go_faster/) uses KVM
- [Oracle OLVM](https://blogs.oracle.com/virtualization/announcing-oracle-linux-virtualization-manager) uses KVM
- ... probably many more

KVM is "just" a hypervisor with an API, many companies build tools around it to make it easy to use. No one expects you to use KVM directly (although it is possible).

Comment: To be clear: I already knew this ([and even said as much in the question](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+companies+use+kvm)). What I asked is not **who** uses the hypervisor, but **how** they use it. Are the tools they use in-house/internal/proprietary? Do they use commercially-available solutions? If so, what *do* they use?